# Greedy Best-First Search Performance for Tree and Graph Space

Tags: search-algorithms, graph-traversal, greedy-algorithms, search-trees

I am currently reviewing the GBFS algorithm and when looking at its completeness I am confused between the difference of it being

1. not optimal in Tree Search for Finite and Infinite Spaces
2. that it is optimal for finite Graph State spaces but not when infinite?

Anyone able to help pick this apart and explain it?